# How can Kayak open so many popups on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, popups

I have all options for popup blocking enabled. Still, even without interacting with the page (tab is not even active, I'm reading reviews for the hotel in another tab) Kayak opens 2 to 4 windows in the background.

How do they do that?

Comment: look at the source data, scream and run.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any add-ons installed? You could try Ad-block Plus Pop-up Blocker.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/adblock-plus-pop-up-addon/

Comment: This is not answer. When you answer a question, the answer should provide a solution to the question: see [answer].

Comment: @user99572isfine The OP is asking how to stop "the madness" of popups, so suggesting to use a popup-blocker seems like an adequate answer to me.

Comment: http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Why%3F:Answer_a_question_with_a_question%3F

Comment: good point @slhck I removed that phrase now. Mostly trying to learn which standards they are abusing. Most popup hacks use clicks to fake to the browser that the action is user initiated and so desired. in this case there was no interaction with the page.